# Customize/Extend Spring's @Async support for shiro

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, shiro

I'm using Spring's `@EnableAsync` feature to execute methods asynchronously. For security I'm using Apache Shiro. In the code that is executed asynchronously I need to have access to the Shiro subject that was attached to the thread that triggered the async call.

Shiro supports using an existing subject in a different thread by associating the subject with the `Callable` that is to be executed on the different thread (see [here](https://shiro.apache.org/subject.html#a-different-thread)):

```
Subject.associateWith(Callable)
```

Unfortunately I don't have direct access to the `Callable` as this stuff is encapsulated by Spring. I found that I would need to extend Spring's `AnnotationAsyncExecutionInterceptor` to associate my subject with the created `Callable` (that's the easy part).

By problem is now how to make Spring use my custom `AnnotationAsyncExecutionInterceptor` instead of the default one. The default one is created in `AsyncAnnotationAdvisor` and `AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`. I can of course extend these classes as well, but this only shifts to problem as I need the make Spring use my extended classes again.

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

I would be fine with adding a new custom async annotation as well. But I don't think this would be much of a help.

---

**UPDATE:**
Actually my finding that `AnnotationAsyncExecutionInterceptor` would need to be customized was wrong. By chance I stumbled across `org.apache.shiro.concurrent.SubjectAwareExecutorService` which does pretty exactly what I want and made me think I could simply provide a custom executor instead of customizing the interceptor. See my answer for details.

Comment: Is it an option for You to: 1 re-write your 'async methods' to return Callables 2. To kick em off (`call()`) manually (in a spring configured executionPool)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to achieve what I want - shiro subject is automatically bound and unbound to tasks that are executed by spring's async support - by providing an extended version of the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`:

```
public class SubjectAwareTaskExecutor extends ThreadPoolTaskExecutor {

  @Override
  public void execute(final Runnable aTask) {
    final Subject currentSubject = ThreadContext.getSubject();
    if (currentSubject != null) {
      super.execute(currentSubject.associateWith(aTask));
    } else {
      super.execute(aTask);
    }
  }

  ... // override the submit and submitListenable method accordingly
}
```

To make spring use this executor I had to implement an `AsyncConfigurer` that returns my custom executor:

```
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {

  @Override
  public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
    final SubjectAwareTaskExecutor executor = new SubjectAwareTaskExecutor();
    executor.setBeanName("async-executor");
    executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
  }

  @Override
  public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    return new SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler();
  }
}
```

With this change the parent Thread's subject will automatically be available in methods that are annotated with `@Async` and - probably even more important - the subject will be de-attached from the thread after execution of the asynchronous method.

Comment: Ty for sharing your solution!