# How pass context in multithreading threading

Tags: java, multithreading, jax-rs

We use multithreading and need the context of the calling thread in each sub-thread. We're using Spring 4.3.

For example:

```
final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    ...
    try {
        // take the security context from the caller
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        doOperations()
```

This approach works fine for the Security context. It's passed from the caller thread (rest endpoint) and passes it to each created completable future.

At a given Class in the call chain, I've following construct:

```
@Context
protected ProvisioningContext provisioningContext;  
@Context
protected UriInfo uriInfo;
```

How do I pass all contexts correctly in the newly created thread?

Approaches like `ThreadContext.getContext()` are not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement something similar to what I described here

[Customize/Extend Spring's @Async support for shiro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46839178/4323935)

That is:

- Use Spring's `@Async` annotation to execute tasks in different threads
- Implement a custom `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` that associates the current context(s) with the to be executed task
- Make spring use this task executor by implementing a `AsyncConfigurer`

If you want to use something like `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` or local executor services, you will end up with a lot of duplicated code compared to approached outlined above - using a thread pool that is managed by spring.

Especially for something like the authentication context it is important to take care of removing the context from the thread as well. Otherwise the context might still be attached to the thread if it is recycled be the executor service to execute another task.